# errors after installing jquery package

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete, asp.net-mvc-4

i created a very small mvc4 internet application that has an autocomplete textbox on the home page. everything worked fine until i updated jquery using the nuget package manager to version 1.8.2, since then i get an `Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method` error thrown by this function:

```
function reduce( elem, size, border, margin ) {
    $.each( side, function() {
    size -= parseFloat( $.curCSS( elem, "padding" + this, true) ) || 0;
        if ( border ) {
            size -= parseFloat( $.curCSS( elem, "border" + this + "Width", true) ) || 0;
        }
        if ( margin ) {
            size -= parseFloat( $.curCSS( elem, "margin" + this, true) ) || 0;
        }
    });
    return size;
```

in the `jquery-ui-1.8.20.js` file.

this is how i call my script and styles in the `_Layout.cshtml` page:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

and the home page with the textbox:

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("AutoComplete", "Home", FormMethod.Get, new { style = "text-align: center;" }))
{
    <input  type="text"  id="autocomplete"  name="key"  data-autocomplete=" @Url.Action("AutoCompleteData", "Home")"  /> 
}
@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#autocomplete').each(function () {
                $(this).autocomplete({
                    source: $(this).attr('data-autocomplete')
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

i tried changing the order of the scripts and styles call but it didn't help.
the same code worked perfectly before the update.
any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
i downloaded the newest jquery-ui files and added them to my project. I'm not receiving any errors now but when typing something to the textbox it looks like this:[image: autocomplete]
(the suggestions hide a part of the textbox and the bullets are visible),
after a refresh the suggestion are located fine but the bullets are still visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i downloaded the newest jquery files and replaced the ones installed by nuget, no luck!
eventually i copied the content directory and the scripts directory form a new mvc4 project and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

.curCSS() has been deprecated for a while and has now been taken out of jQuery.
It must be replaced it by the .css() method. Try to use an up-to-date version of jQuery UI.
See http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11921